# Tableau Get Inactive User for the Last 30 Days

Tags: tableau-api

How can we get a list of users who has not accessed Tableau for the last 30 days?
I tried using the rebuild report (site_status) but It is not listing the users. Can we query the tables or is there any dashboard that gives this information, please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to Tableau Server's internal Postgres database and pull a variety of usage data. Work with your server admin to enable and grant you permissions.

https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm

Once you have that, there's a Users table with a login_at field that will contain the most recent login of users.
https://tableau.github.io/tableau-data-dictionary/2019.4/data_dictionary.htm#users_anchor

Comment: Hi Bernardo, thanks for the reply. 
Yes, I have received access to the Tableau repository, I'm looking at the tables.